# Server error when trying to reach a domain [Zappa]

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, virtualenv, zappa

I deployed a website to AWS using Zappa (a few hours ago).

I can access the API gateway url but when I try to access the domain url on a browser I get a server not found error.

Does anyone know a solution? Or do you need to wait 24 hours or something..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `certify` to make your zappa exposed via custom domains.

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#ssl-certification

and

https://edgarroman.github.io/zappa-django-guide/walk_domain/